# scala passing function with underscore produces a function not a value

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Hi I was writing any possible variations of passing a function to map, my initial understanding that they would all produce the same result, but I found that the lines 2, 3, actually produced different output, and line 4 is a mystery to me

```
def g(v: Int) = List(v - 1, v, v + 1)
    val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    // map with some variations
    println(l.map { x => g(x) })
    println(l.map { (_: Int) => g(_) }) // line 2
    println(l.map { (_) => g(_) }) // line 3
    println(l.map { _ => }) // line 4
    println(l.map { g(_) })
    println(l.map { g })
```

Output:

```
List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5), List(4, 5, 6))
List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
List((), (), (), (), ())
List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5), List(4, 5, 6))
List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5), List(4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the ones returning the results you expected:

```
println(l.map { x => g(x) })
println(l.map { g(_) })
println(l.map { g })
```

One can infer that all three are the same thing. Actually, the third one depends on the fact that `map` *expects* a function, but, truthfully, they really are basically the same.

Starting with the last, `g` is a named function. You defined it with the name `g`, taking an `Int` and returning a `List[Int]`.

Next, the first one: `x => g(x)`. This is an *anonymous* function. It doesn't have a name, and it's definition is right there, where it is written: it takes a parameter `x` (which was inferred to be `Int`), and returns a `List[Int]` (because that's what calling `g(x)`) does.

Now, `g` and `x => g(x)` are not the same thing. They have the *same type*, `Int => List[Int]`, but they are different functions, just like, if I defined `def h(x: Int) = g(x)`, `h` and `g` would have the same type but would not be the same function.

That leaves `g(_)`. That is a syntactic sugar for `x => g(x)`. In this case, `g(_)` and `x => g(x)` are really the same thing. This is a special case of something like `_ + _`, an expression where the underscores represent the parameters to a function. One would think that `g(_)` would be equal to `g(x => x)`, but this case, where the expansion would be `x => x`, is an exception that "moves" the function to the next outer expression boundary.

So, let's see the cases that gave you doubts:

```
println(l.map { (_: Int) => g(_) }) // line 2
```

First, we know that `g(_)` is the same thing as `x => g(x)`, so this line would be equivalent to

```
println(l.map { (_: Int) => (x => g(x)) }) // line 2
```

The remaining underscore is completely unrelated to the one in `g(_)`. An underscore in place of a parameter name means *the parameter name is irrelevant*. It's essentially the same thing as writing this:

```
println(l.map { (unusedVar: Int) => (x => g(x)) }) // line 2
```

As for the type, it is `Int => (Int => List[Int])`. So, when you map the list, you get a list of `Int => List[Int]`-- functions! -- which is what gets printed.

```
println(l.map { (_) => g(_) }) // line 3
```

Same thing as line 2, except that you omit the type of the parameter, which is going to be inferred anyway.

Finally,

```
println(l.map { _ => }) // line 4
```

The type of that is `Int => Unit`. It simply takes a parameter, which is ignored, doesn't do anything, and returns a `Unit` (which is something like the `void` type in Java).

`Unit` is a type for things whose value doesn't matter. A function *has* to return something, because that's what functions do. When that something doesn't matter, we use the `Unit` type, which has only one value. The sole value of `Unit` is written as `()`.

For example, this returns `true`:

```
def test = {
  val a = println("Println returns Unit")
  val b: Unit = () // the only possible value
  a == b
}
```

And that's why you see a list of `()` get printed for line 4: it's a `List[Unit]`, and, therefore, all elements of it are `()`.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for, specially in a language like scala,  Thanks A LOT !

Answer (score 6):

These are all equivalent ways of passing the application of the function `g` to every element of the `List`:

```
l.map { x => g(x) }
l.map { g(_) }
l.map { g }

res17: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(3, 4, 5), List(4, 5, 6))
```

These are equivalent ways of mapping all of the elements of the `List` to an unapplied function like `g`:

```
l.map { (_: Int) => g(_) }
l.map { (_) => g(_) }
```

That is, each element of the mapped list is actually `g`.

```
scala> l.map { (_: Int) => g(_) }.head
res23: Int => List[Int] = <function1>
scala> res23(0)
res24: List[Int] = List(-1, 0, 1)
```

In fact, the only difference between those two is  the parenthesis and type annotation. They are both equivalent to:

```
l.map { _ => g(_) }
```

The following just maps all the elements of the `List` to `Unit`:

```
l.map { _ => }
```

Comment: I would add for further clarity that 2&3 are equivalent to `l.map{x=>(_:Int)=>g(_)}` where the `x` is merely thrown away.