# What is the different between below two statements

Tags: scala

```
def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = langs.map(lang => (lang, occurrencesOfLang(lang ,rdd))).sortBy(-_._2)
```

```
def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = langs.map(_ => (_, occurrencesOfLang(_, rdd))).sortBy(-_._2).reverse
```

The IDE says no error for the first one, but second one is marked as error. 
Why I could not replace `lang` as `_`?

Comment: `_ =>` means "ignore the in-parameter", "don't give it a name", "just throw it away", "it won't be used".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is since in the second you're using '_' inside the definition of the passing anonymous function.

Thus,

```
langs.map(_ => (_ , occurrencesOfLang(_,rdd)))
```

will expand to something like

```
langs.map(x$1 => (x$2:Any) => (x$2, occurrencesOfLang(x$2,rdd))
```

thus will return **List[String=> (Any) => (String,Int)]** instead of **List[(String,Int)]**

This is because it is equivalent to writing

```
langs.map(x => (_:Any) => (_, occurrencesOfLang(_,rdd))
```

As explained here: [What are the rules to govern underscore to define anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125850/what-are-the-rules-to-govern-underscore-to-define-anonymous-function)

A much cleaner explanation with a suitable example can be found here: [scala passing function with underscore produces a function not a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118146/scala-passing-function-with-underscore-produces-a-function-not-a-value)